# How to exporting data from a List<T> to excel file?

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a `List<Person>` which is bound to a grid view.
I want to export all the values to an excel file.
My person class is as follows:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to do it?
Please suggest....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need an SDK to save as the xlsx format. I dont know where to get the openxml sdk to do it, but here is a code snippet to save as a CSV which can be opened in excel as well.

```
List<Person> persons; // populated earlier
using(StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("myfile.csv"))
{
   foreach(Person person in persons)
   {
     wr.WriteLine(person.Name + "," + person.City + "," + person.Age);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run through your list with a `foreach` loop, and create a [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), one line per person.  CSV files can be opened directly by Excel.